# Has any mathematician constructed a physical, (global), ball model of $\Bbb R^3?$

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, math-history, compactification

> Q: Has any mathematician constructed a physical, (global), ball model of $\Bbb R^3?$

For example, to map $\Bbb R^3$ inside $S^2$ you can do, $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,z)/\sqrt{1+r^2}$ so, $\left(\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}},\dfrac y{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}},\dfrac z{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right).$

Comment: The crochet is a model of the hyperbolic plane in the sense that the distances along the hyperbolic  plane match the distances measured by walking along the surface of the crochet. Because the distances in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the distances of normal 3D euclidean space, wouldn't a ball model of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ be simply a ball?

Comment: I am suspicious about the statement that mathematicians believed such models were impossible, seeing how certain embedding results were known since 1955, and W. Thurston made a model in the 70s out of paper. See e.g. http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~dwh/papers/crochet/crochet.html

Comment: Or one could use a 3D compass like the kind that [Leonardo da Vinci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_and_inventions_of_Leonardo_da_Vinci) made.  However, the medium in this proposed scenerio is still hypothetical.  :)

Comment: To supplement the earlier comments, the crochet models of Taimina and the paper models of Thurston are merely *local* models of the hyperbolic plane. And in fact local models of $\mathbb H^2$ have been known since the 19th century: the [tractricoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere#Tractricoid), sometimes also called the "pseudo-sphere", is such a local model. The "ball" suggestion of @user3257842 therefore answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @user3257842: Your comment would make a good answer to this question.

Comment: @LeeMosher A ball model of $\Bbb R^3$ is a way of representing the entirety of $\Bbb R^3$ inside $S^2.$ As a result of this compactification the geodesics become curved, and meet at points at infinity.

Comment: That's fine, although I'm pointing out it does not match the motivation from the early part of your question. The crochet model is *not* a ball model in that same sense. It is instead a *local* model in the same sense as the tracticoid, and also in the same sense as the local "ball model" of $\mathbb R^3$ proposed by @user3257842.

Comment: Okay, I'm just confused because in order to physically visualize a ball model of $\Bbb R^3$ you'd want to see the structure of the geodesics (finitely many) inside $S^2,$ so I don't think saying that a ball model of $\Bbb R^3$ is a ball really helps for this physical realization. If you just look at a ball, you can't see the structure inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a small model of $\left(\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}},\dfrac y{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}},\dfrac z{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$ for
 $x,y,z \in\{-2,1,0,1,2\}$ (ie. $5^3 = 125$ points in total) and the grid lines passing trough them with red length-wise parallel lines, blue width-wise parallel lines and green height-wise parallel lines. You can download the model 
[here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=48403800177788382007) 
and view it with [View3dscene](https://castle-engine.io/view3dscene.php).

[image] 
Geometrically, I don't know if there's much to say about the model. The sphere which is the boundary of the ball represents infinity (the metric distance from a point in the interior of the ball to a hypothetical point on the boundary of the ball is infinite), so the closer you get to the boundary, the "denser" the points will be.

Also, parallel co-planar lines will intersect at infinity, at two radially opposite points of the sphere. 
[image]

As expected, it looks "most" Euclidean when looking from the center.

[image]

Comment: could you have used four colors?

Comment: There are 4: red, green, blue for the lines and orange for the points. Tough the points were drawn as small spheres cause I didn't know how to make them mesh right otherwise.

Comment: No I mean $4$ colors for the lines.

Comment: The lines split into $3$ sets, parallel to the  $x$,  $y$ and $z$ axis so I choose a color for each of those.  As they are now, I don't think they group naturally into $4$ sets. It's the 3d equivalent of red for horizontal lines, blue for vertical.